# PHP 'stops' (is empty) after session_start();

Tags: php, session

I have a problem using the php method session_start();

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    session_start();
    echo "Sesstion Started";
}
```

This is at the very beginning auf the php-file. If I execute this on my webserver and the requested method is POST, the page stays empty and it seems as if nothing is executed after the session_start();

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Cheers,
Cheeesi

Comment: Is error reporting activated?

Comment: write `ini_set('display_errors','on'); error_reporting(E_ALL)` and tell us the OP

Comment: Chances are your `www` user doesn't have write access to the `sessions` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me running into this issue I would simply do this;

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    session_start();
    echo "Sesstion Started";
}
else
{
    echo "Error : Session NOT Started";
}
?>
```

This would help with the "empty" output until you can track down the error reporting.

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect. On the rest of the page there is a html-form where I submit two values (using post).